# applescript that works up until the first `end tell`

Tags: applescript, finder, adobe-illustrator

I'm new to applescript, and I have a script that works… up until the first `end tell`.
Do I need to use POSIX with my folder reference?

I want to download a file just prior to running the script, then have the script make the folders and leave the name on the clipboard – this is the part I have – and then move the downloaded file to the folder that was just created (not a subfolder), open this folder, and open the file in Illustrator.

Here's what I have so far -

```
tell application "Finder"
    set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
    set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"
    set newfoldername to JobName
    set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:newfoldername}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:JobName & "_Seps"}
    set the clipboard to JobName
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    open folder with properties {name:JobName}
end tell

move contents of downloads folder to folder with properties {name:JobName}

tell application "Adobe illustrator" 
    open files in folder with properties {name:JobName}
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran through it quickly but it should look more like this in my mind.

```
    tell application "Finder"
        set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
        set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"
        set newfoldername to JobName
        set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:newfoldername}
        make new folder at newfo with properties {name:JobName & "_Seps"}
        set the clipboard to JobName
        move entire contents of downloads folder to newfo
    end tell

    tell application "System Events" to set FileList to get every file of folder newfo

    tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
        repeat with CurrentFile in FileList
            try
               open CurrentFile
            end try 
        end repeat
    end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
set the clipboard to JobName
set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"
set newfo to (loc as text) & JobName

set newPath to POSIX path of newfo & "/" & JobName & "_Seps"
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of newPath

tell application "Finder"
    move entire contents of (path to downloads folder) to folder newfo
    open folder newfo
end tell
```

Comment: It's telling me --  mkdir: /desktopJob_Name/Job_Name_Seps: Permission denied -- Do I need password info included?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way to get it done - thanks for the help!!! Much Appreciated!!! I'll put the script up here - it actually does exactly what I wanted and will save me a lot of time - I got rid of the part to choose the folder location since I put it in 3 different places once finished any way.
This does all the grunt work and serves the downloaded file up in Illustrator - just make sure the file has finished downloading before running this script.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter Job Name:" default answer "Job_Name")
    set loc to desktop
    set newfoldername to JobName
    set newfo to make new folder at loc with properties {name:newfoldername}
    make new folder at newfo with properties {name:JobName & "_Seps"}
    set the clipboard to JobName
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    open folder JobName
    move (files of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:YOURNAMEHERE:Downloads") to newfo
end tell
tell application "Adobe Illustrator"
    open files in newfo
end tell
```